# How can this linked list reversal with recursion work?

Tags: java, c#, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am looking at this recursive implementation of a function that reverses a given linked list:

```
static Node reverse(Node head) {
    if(head == null) {
        return head;
    }

    // last node or only one node
    if(head.next == null) {
        return head;
    }

    Node newHeadNode = reverse(head.next);

    // change references for middle chain
    head.next.next = head;
    head.next = null;

    // send back new head node in every recursion
    return newHeadNode;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
    llist.insertNode(20);
    llist.insertNode(4);
    llist.insertNode(15);
    llist.insertNode(85);
      
    Node llistReversed = reverse(llist.head);
    printSinglyLinkedList(llistReversed, " ");
}
```

So the linked list nodes are:  85  15  4  20

I thought that after the call to `reverse` `head.next` would point to the second node with value 15? If so, how is this code reversing this linked list (recursively)?

Comment: The code you provided does not define `reverse`. Please provide enough code to see what this is about, and also provide the code that builds the example list and makes the call.

Comment: @trincot    Sorry about that, here is one of the solutions I found, and thanks in advance ; https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursively-reversing-a-linked-list-a-simple-implementation/

Comment: I see. I have edited your question adding a bit more code from that source.

Comment: @trincot   Thanks much. I think my biggest problem is that; in my mind  (head.next == null) {  return head;} points to 15. But I understand your comment to say that it points to 15, but since it's not null, it goes to the tail of the list, but I can't see how that would happen, without some sort of iteration. So in my mind, either the recursive call keeps iterating thru until it reaches null, or the head.next keeps iterating by itself until it finds a null! That's where I'm stuck. Thanks

Comment: *"But I understand your comment"*: not sure which of the above comments you refer to. Or is this a comment to my answer? In that case, can you please comment below my answer?

Comment: @trincot  Sorry, I meant your answer

Comment: Please see the addition I did in the middle of my answer, and please place any future comment there, not here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that this works correctly, start with a list having just one node. It is clear that in that case the node is returned as-is by the following `if` statement:

```
if (head.next == null) {
    return head;
}
```

And that is indeed what you would expect: the reversal of a list with one node should not change anything to that list; the head should reference the same single node.

### Induction

We could go on now and analyse the algorithm for 2 nodes, 3 nodes, then 4, then 5, etc. But we can instead use a proof of induction here:

Let's say we have a list of any size greater than 1, like this:

```
 head
  ↓              
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐                        ┌───────────┐
│ value: 85 │    │ value: 15 │                        │ value: 20 │
│ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ ...more nodes...——→ │ next:null │
└───────────┘    └───────────┘                        └───────────┘
```

We will then execute:

```
Node newHeadNode = reverse(head.next);
```

`head->next` is a reference to the second node, the one with value 15. This reference is passed on to the recursive call of `reverse`.

Now each execution of `reverse` has its own execution context, and in that deeper context we get a new instance of a `head` variable. It is initialised with the value that was passed as argument. So in this case *that* `head` refers to the node with value 15.

To this recursive execution context of `reverse` this is the *first* node of a list (as it doesn't know about the node with 85), and its own `head` variable references it:

```
                  head
                   ↓              
                 ┌───────────┐                        ┌───────────┐
                 │ value: 15 │                        │ value: 20 │
                 │ next: ———————→ ...more nodes...——→ │ next:null │
                 └───────────┘                        └───────────┘
```

**We now will *assume* that this call will reverse *that* shorter list correctly** and will return the old tail node, which has become the new head (with value 20):

```
                  head                                (returned)
                   ↓                                    ↓        
                 ┌───────────┐                        ┌───────────┐
                 │ value: 15 │                        │ value: 20 │
                 │ next:null │ ←——...more nodes... ←——————— :next │
                 └───────────┘                        └───────────┘
```

Executing `return`, the deeper execution context disappears, and the returned reference is assigned to `newHeadNode` in the *outer* execution context, where `head` still refers to the node with value 85:

```
 head                                                  newHeadNode
  ↓                                                     ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐                        ┌───────────┐
│ value: 85 │    │ value: 15 │                        │ value: 20 │
│ next: ———————→ │ next:null │ ←——...more nodes... ←——————— :next │
└───────────┘    └───────────┘                        └───────────┘
```

Note how we *assume* that:

- all the links in that shorter list now effectively point "the other way";
- the node that follows `head` has become a tail node with its `next` property set to `null`;
- the new head is the previous tail node and a reference to it is returned by the recursive function call.

Then this is executed:

```
head.next.next = head;
```

Which is reflected here:

```
 head                                                  newHeadNode
  ↓                                                     ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐                        ┌───────────┐
│ value: 85 │    │ value: 15 │                        │ value: 20 │
│ next: ———————→ │           │                        │           │
│           │ ←——————— :next │ ←——...more nodes... ←——————— :next │
└───────────┘    └───────────┘                        └───────────┘
```

And:

```
head.next = null;
```

This makes sense, because if the list has been reversed, then the head is now the tail, and there should be no other node following the tail node:

```
 head                                                  newHeadNode
  ↓                                                     ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐                        ┌───────────┐
│ value: 85 │    │ value: 15 │                        │ value: 20 │
│ next: null│ ←——————— :next │ ←——...more nodes... ←——————— :next │
└───────────┘    └───────────┘                        └───────────┘
```

Finally:

```
return newHeadNode;
```

So... we see that if our assumption is right, then we have correctly reversed the list.

As we verified it works for a list with 1 node, and we now also found that if it works for a list of size  it also works for a list of size +1, we have proof that it works for any list.

### How `head` "moves"

You can imagine how the variable `head` will "walk" to the next node at each deeper recursive call, until it reaches the last node in the list. Then the base case kicks in and no more recursion happens. As the execution backtracks out of recursion, `head` seems to move back in the opposite direction back to where it started.

Although it can help to see it that way, this is not entirely correct: each execution context of `reverse` has its own version of `head` that actually never moves. It is a constant reference. However, as each recursive call gets `head->next` as argument, the new `head` variable that exists in the deeper execution context, is initialised with that *next* node. And so each separate execution context of `reverse` has a `head` variable that references a *different* node. And whenever the execution of one call of `reverse` ends, execution will fall back into a previous execution context where we deal again with a variable `head` that didn't move and still references the same node as was the case before the recursive call.

Comment: I added some more explanation in the middle and at the very end. Please let me know whether this clarifies how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For a usual singly-linked list, yes, `head.next` points or refers to the node containing 15. In the first invocation of the recursive method, that is. In the next invocation it will be 4, then 20.

Looking at the first invocation (where `head.next` points to 15) `reverse(head.next)` returns the new head after reversing 15 4 20 into 20 4 15, that is, a pointer or reference to the 20 node.

How the method works: After the recursive call the 15 node is made to point to the 85 node, and the 85 node to nothing. Notice that we are still using the old `head` in these operations. This makes sure that 85 is appended after 20 4 15, so finishes the reverse operation. Finally the new head that we got from the recursive call, the reference to 20, is returned.

Two suggestions: Draw it on paper. And run it in your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped to see the full code including the method signature for `reverse` but I assume that `head` is not actually the head of the entire list but the head of a portion of the list passed when calling reverse recursively

As such, other than the null check, which serves to stop recursion when the end of the list has been reached, because the first thing the recursive method does is call itself passing the next node in the list it effectively travels all the way to the end of the list then starts coming back as the stack unwinds

Each iteration of the method thus establishes a reference to head that is a particular node in the list and hasn’t had its next’s next modified yet. By making itself the next one after its next it moves itself to the end of the list but it’s probably easier to conceive that the direction of the link is reversed:

```
A>B>C>D
```

If we travel all the way to D then come back one (because D’s next is null) so we are at C, by making C’s next (D)’s next equal to C we have pointed D back at C which serves to turn the linkage between C and D around

```
A>B>C><D
```

C still points to D too, but now D points back to C

Then we do `head.next = null` which stops C pointing to D..

```
  null
    ᐱ
A>B>C<D
```

..but that’s usually a pointless operation because it’s just about to be overwritten again..

..when we step back to B and make B’s nextnext point to B, which is a way of saying “make C’s next point to B”

```
A>B><C<D
```

That pointing C at null we just did is moot because we just pointed C at B, but it does have a use in one case..

.. eventually we will reach A, point A’s next (B) back at A then set A’s next to null and we really need to do that because there is nothing left to process. If we didn’t set null on A’s next we’d never be able to get to the end of the list in the future because it cycles (B points to A points to B points to A etc)

```
null 
 ᐱ
 A<B<C<D
```

Our list is reversed

Final note, that after zipping down to the end of the list we effectively carry D all the way back as the newHeadNode and return it so it can capture it as the new head(otherwise we’d lose access to all the list except A)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the link, which I copied off of an online site; https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php                                                                   Sorry gots to get up early, but I will read your comment first in the morning. Thanks so much

Comment: Sorry; https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursively-reversing-a-linked-list-a-simple-implementation/